# Winforms Treeview Node Tooltip Customization

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, treeview

For displaying **tooltips** in a **treeview** I set `ToolTipText` for each node and `ShowNodeToolTip=True`. Ok that's easy. My question is now, how can I customize the tooltips appearance? How can I change for example the **time the ToolTip remains visible** or the **background color**? Or should I use the tooltip control for that?

Answer (score 8):

TreeView has its own built-in ToolTip "control", you can't change the way it behaves.  If you want to customize it then just use your own ToolTip component.  The TreeView.NodeMouseHover event is a very good event to trigger it:

```
    private void treeView1_NodeMouseHover(object sender, TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs e) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Node.ToolTipText)) {
            toolTip1.Show(e.Node.ToolTipText, treeView1);
        }
    }
```

Note that ToolTip.Show() has several overloads that lets you adjust position and duration of the tip.  Changing the tip's background color requires setting the ToolTip.OwnerDraw property to True and implementing its Draw event.